# How can I create a view connecting two tables show which entities in one table are not connected to entities from the other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a view of persons and contracts that they have not yet subscribed to. So far I've come up with a nested select to collect the foreign keys in my Subscription table, but I'm stuck with how to use this information to get contracts a person doesn't have.

```
SELECT s.PersonId as pId, s.ContractID as cId
FROM dbo.Subscription AS s
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Person as p ON s.PersonId = p.Id
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Contract as c ON s.ContractID = c.Id
WHERE p.Id IN (SELECT PersonId FROM dbo.Subscription)
```

Pseudocode of what I want to do:

1. Get Persons that have Contracts
2. For each Person, get contract they don't have
3. Display Persons and each missing contract for Person

Schema (edited to remove business info):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contract]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [ContractNumber] NUMERIC(16) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
    Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL         
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Subscription]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [PersonID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    [ContractID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Subscription_Person] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonID]) REFERENCES [Person]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Subscription_Contract] FOREIGN KEY ([ContractID]) REFERENCES [Contract]([Id])
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `cross join` and `not exists` solution:

```
SELECT p.Id as pId, c.ID as cId
from dbo.Person as p
cross join dbo.Contract as c
WHERE p.Id IN (SELECT PersonId FROM dbo.Subscription as s1)
and not exists(select 1 from dbo.Subscription as s2 where s2.PersonId = p.Id and s2.ContractID = c.Id)
```

> 1. Get Persons that have Contracts

You already did this correctly with `WHERE p.Id IN (SELECT PersonId FROM dbo.Subscription as s1)`

> 2. For each Person, get contract they don't have

First we take all combinations with `cross join`, then we filter out the ones you don't want with `not exists`

For (3.) We just `select` what we want

Answer (score 0):

use left join

```
SELECT p.*,s.*,c.*
FROM dbo.Person as p
left OUTER JOIN  dbo.Subscription AS s ON s.PersonId = p.Id
left join Contract c on s.ContractID=c.Id
```